# Why does my script FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: when ran through Run Dialog, but not through command or IDE

Tags: python, openpyxl

The program is supposed to take some information from the URL it creates, parse it and extract and filter the data, and copy to an excel document based on player position (using openpyxl). The program does what it is supposed to when ran through Pycharm and the Windows command line. However, when I try to run the program through the Run dialog (using sys) it gives me:

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:`

Is there a reason I get an error through the Run Dialog but not the IDE or Command Line? I am just beginning so I understand if my code is sloppy/could be improved (always appreciate tips! :D)

The script references a different script based on position.

Main Script:

```
mport sys
from get_position import *
from get_stats_QB import *
from get_stats_WR import *
from get_stats_RB import *


# CREATE VARIABLES/DATA STRUCTURES
positions = ['QB', 'RB', 'WR', 'TE']

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    name = sys.argv[1] + ' ' + sys.argv[2]
    pos = sys.argv[3]
    assert sys.argv[3] in positions, 'Not a valid player position.'

else:
    name = input('Enter player name: ')
    pos = input('Enter play position (Example: WR, QB, etc.): ')

# CREATE ASSERTIONS:
assert len(sys.argv) <= 4, 'Too many arguments given.'


# CREATE NEEDED HTML FROM FIRST NAME
player = name.split()
first_name = player[0]
fname_2 = first_name[:2]

# CREATE NEEDED HTML PARTS FROM LAST NAME
last_name = player[1]
lname_let = last_name[:1]
lname_4 = last_name[:4]

num = '00'

url = f'https://www.pro-football-reference.com/players/{lname_let}/{lname_4}{fname_2}{num}.htm'

position = get_position(url)

while True:
    if position != pos:
        num = int(num) + 1
        if num < 10:
            num = '0' + str(num)
        else:
            num = str(num)
        url = f'https://www.pro-football-reference.com/players/{lname_let}/{lname_4}{fname_2}{num}.htm'
        position =  get_position(url)
    else:
        break

if pos == 'QB':
    get_stats_qb(url, 'QB', name)
elif pos == 'WR':
    get_stats_wr(url, 'WR', name)
elif pos == 'RB':
    get_stats_rb(url, 'RB', name)
```

Referenced Script:

```
def get_stats_qb(url, pos, name):
    name = name
    result = requests.get(url).text
    doc = BeautifulSoup(result, 'html.parser')
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('QB_stats.xlsx')

    # ENSURES THE PLAYER IS THE CORRECT POSITION
    assert pos == 'QB', 'This is not a quarterback.'

    # GETS THE TABLE OF THE PLAYER STATS
    try:
        tag = 'switcher_passing'
        main = doc.find(id=tag)
        table = main.find(id='div_passing')
        data = table.find(id='passing')
        stats = data.find('tbody')
    except:
        tag = 'all_passing'
        main = doc.find(id=tag)
        print(main)
        table = main.find(id='div_passing')
        data = table.find(id='passing')
        stats = data.find('tbody')


    # GET THE DATES FROM THE TABLE
    thead = stats.find_all('th')
    dates = []
    headers = list(thead)
    for year in headers:
        year = year.text
        if len(year) > 4:
            year = year[:4]
        dates.append(year)

    # SET COUNTING VARIABLE FOR YEARS ACTIVE
    if len(dates) > 4:
        dates = dates[-5:]

    rook_yr = int(dates[0])
    total_stats = []

    # REMOVES WHITESPACE/EMPTY LISTS
    st_list = list(stats)
    for item in st_list:
        if item == ' ':
            st_list.remove(item)

    # FIND ALL TABLE DATA WITH LOOP REMOVING THE MOST RECENT YEAR.
    stats_list = list(st_list)
    del stats_list[-1]
    if len(stats_list) > 4:
        stats_list = stats_list[-4:]

    for item in stats_list:
        # LIST OF ALL THE STATS
        item = item.find_all('td')
        item = list(item)

        # CREATE LIST OF STATS FOR EACH YEAR AND ADDS THE YEAR TO THE BEGINNING.
        year_stat = []
        year_stat.append(name)
        year_stat.append(rook_yr)

        # ADDS THE PLAYER STATS FROM THE YEAR TO THE LIST OF THAT YEAR.
        for stat in item:
            year_stat.append(stat.text)
        rook_yr += 1
        total_stats.append(year_stat)
        # print(year_stat)

    # OPEN EXCEL WORKBOOK
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_path)
    sheets = list(wb.sheetnames)

    for i in range(0, len(total_stats)):
        for st_year in total_stats:
            if str(st_year[1]) == sheets[i]:
                ws = wb[sheets[i]]
                ws.append(total_stats[i])

    wb.save('QB_stats.xlsx')
    return 'Done'
```

Thank you!

Comment: Remember that this will look for files in the "current directory" of your process.  When you use Windows+R to start an app, the initial directory is your home directory, not the directory containing the script.  You can do `os.chdir` to change to that, by fetching the path to your executable from `__file__`.

Comment: Thank you! So, if I am understanding this correctly, I need to change the initial directory for Windows + R? Or is this something I need to change in my script?

Comment: I figured it out! Thank you for the tip! Gave me something to go on.